# Обработка голоса / TTS

Tags: аудио, tts

У меня есть доступ к игровым файлам и всем звукам из игры, которые представлены в этом видео: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZGMy4EFDzTI
Я хочу сделать эти фразы на русском языке, без потери этого голоса / эффекта. Я пробовал обрезать звуки (букв) через Audacity но при попытке получить слово ничего не понятно. Пробовал так же записать своим голосом звуки тоже ничего не понятно. Что я делаю не так? Как нужно записать звуки, чтобы объединять их в слова? Это ведь работает в TTS Windows.
Какими звуковыми эффектами можно получить такой голос? Нейросеть из-за эффектов неправильно обучается. Смотрел разные видео и пробовал разные программы по обработке голоса, пока что не нашёл ничего интересного.